# limitation of <datalist> </datalist> PHP

Tags: php

```
  <input list="browsers" name="browser">
  <datalist id="browsers">
    <option value="Internet Explorer">
    <option value="Firefox">
    <option value="Chrome">
    <option value="Opera">
    <option value="Safari">
  </datalist>
  <input type="submit">
```

as you know, this is a datalist, the problem is that some browsers do not support this tag.

1. is there any replacement tag or anyway to fix this problem?

   2. can merge this tag with select tag? i mean have both tags together when some one does not worked, another one work.

Comment: You can use a `select` tag, sure.  Maybe something like a jQuery UI AutoComplete to more closely replicate the functionality?  That would support older browsers (to a reasonable extent, at least).  What does any of this have to do with PHP?

Comment: @David i have not used jquery till now :-s

Comment: Well, that's just one option.  There are a number of options for auto-complete text input functionality, I'm sure.  The point is that if you need to replicate this functionality in older browsers then you're going to have to write some code to do it.

Comment: @david can not join this code with a select tag?

Comment: What do you mean by "join this code"?

Comment: @David  for finding items  also with select and datalist tag, a thing like combo box

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94714/discussion-between-sajad-and-david).

Comment: For older browsers, that would likely be an auto-complete on a text input.  If you want to replicate modern functionality on older browsers then you're going to have to do it manually.  There's no magic wand that will do it for you.  There are, however, very useful plugins for frameworks like jQuery.